# moderncv only working with oldstyle

Tags: moderncv

Hi I'm trying to set up my cv with the `moderncv` class. When I simply try to compile the code with the `\moderncvstyle{oldstyle}` option the code works but  with `\moderncvstyle{casual}` it breaks an I get a lot of errors.

I'm running `pdftex version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20` on manjaro linux. The `moderncv` class is `version 2.0.0`.

How do I get this running with the `casual` option?

Here a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}      
%\moderncvstyle{oldstyle} 
\moderncvstyle{casual}                         
\moderncvcolor{blue} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\name{Hans}{im Glück}
\title{M.Sc.}                             
\address{Glücksstr. 13}{55444 Glücksdorf}{Deutschland \medskip}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\phone[mobile]{+49~(176)~111~2222}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the optional "type" of the phone can be "mobile" (default), "fixed" or "fax"
\phone[fixed]{+49~(765)~1234~5678}
%\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{hglueck@bsp.de}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

\photo[4,0cm][0.2pt]{bewerbungsbild.png}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}



% #################################
% Lebenslauf......................

\makecvtitle

\section{Ausbildung}
% arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{10/04--05/05}{Master}{Karl Tux Institut für Technologie}{}{\textit{Note: 1,1}}{Pinguinkunde, Hauptfächer Prokrastination und Bummelei I, Celebrare maximus und systematische Zeitverschwendung.}

\end{document}
```

The error I got:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.32 \section{Ausbildung}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.32 \section{Ausbildung}

Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

.........
```

Thank you for your quick answer. If I try to compile your corrected MWE I still get the same amount of errors. Probably I  didn't point out enough that I had more errors than the two mentioned in my first post but the log is too long to post here. I uploaded the whole logfile on [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/goc8fkcslge4jrr/mwe_korrigiert.log?dl=0). Besides the errors there are a few  warnings like

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `moderncvfooti',
               but the package provides `moderncvfooti'.

...

LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `moderncvbodyi',
               but the package provides `moderncvbodyi'.

...

LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `moderncvheadii',
               but the package provides `moderncvheadii'.

....

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/fontawesometwo/m/sl' undefined

...

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted
```

Comment: Works okay in a current texlive (if I replace the image). Show the complete log-file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because after deletion of an outdated colortbl.sty the code compiles without problems (see comment in deleted answer of OP)